# How to add custom separator between functions using clang format?

Tags: c++, c, clang, code-formatting, clang-format

I have a C and C++ code base which I format using clang format. I'd like to make my code easy to read by placing separators between functions in the following way:

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
void func1()
{
    // body
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
void func2()
{
    // body
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
void func3()
{
    // body
}
```

Is there a way to automate the adding of this separator line automatically during formatting:

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Doesn't look like it https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html. clang-format isn't able to format to arbitrary styles

Comment: Are you sure that will be a help to readability?

Comment: Instead of a meaningless separator, write some meaningful comment for each function. Any decent IDE will color the comment sufficiently distinctive, so that you can easily see where one function ends and another begins. And you have some documentation as a bonus. (Or is it the other way around?)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I used similar separator. it also help to see column limit (some IDE might provide such functionality, but we might have to see code not in our favorite IDE (as code review on website)).

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [currently available style options](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html), clang-format doesn't have a feature that would let you do that.

However, clang-format preserves comments, so you can manually insert the separators and they won't be reformatted or deleted.
You can also add doc comments (see e.g. [the LSST Stack](https://developer.lsst.io/cpp/api-docs.html)) to your functions, which not only visually separates them, but also has uses beyond that.

If you still want this feature, you can either fork clang-format and implement it yourself, or you can request it by [submitting an issue in the llvm-project repository](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues).